# JS - Date issue with constructor

Tags: javascript, date

I have an issue, and I don´t know what is wrong.

`new Date(2017,3,31).getDate()`
returns `1` (like 1.4., not 31.3.)

`new Date(2017,3,30).getDate()`
returns 30 (as 30.3.), which is correct.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Month starts with `0` for `January`, and ends with `11` for `December` [MDN: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: `3` is April and there is no April 31st. Always read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: This question title is not acceptable; please make it _describe_ the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably expect 3 to be March as it is the third month of the year.

JavaScript months start at 0:

```
0 - January
1 - February
2 - March
...
```

You are trying to create the April 31st, which does not exist. Change it to:

```
new Date(2017, 2, 31).getDate(); // March 31st
```

Comment: @OndraPernica Well, I think this constructor is ambiguous, you are not the first one to do this mistake... :)

Comment: it´s so missleading. Days starts at 1, months at 0.. but ill remember that since now

Comment: There is a long tradition of people making this mistake, JavaScript copied it from Java, Java copied it from C... isn't it obvious ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Months in JavaScript are zero-based, so `Date(2017,3,31)` is actually April 31st, which doesn't exist. So you end up with May 1 instead.

Comment: How so "end up" with May? I think the edit doesn't make sense

Comment: @Matheus - JavaScript says hey, there is no April 31, so here's the correct day. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) notes: _"if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month is 0-based). "_

Comment: aaahh a thought that it is not index (zero) based.. how could I miss that? :D
thank you